# How is setForeground method called without creating instance in java?

Tags: java, class, static, applet

I was looking at an applet code and it struck me.

**My Questions:**

why is `setForeground()` used without an object here despite it being defined as a non-static method in the API

the code is as follows:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
/*<applet code = "swings.class" height = "500" width = "500"></applet>*/

public class Swings extends Applet{
    public void init(){
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        setForeground(Color.red);
        Font f = new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.BOLD,25);
        setFont(f);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Welcome to Applets",100,100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setForeground` is declared as `public` in `Component`, `Swings` is a subclass of `Component`,

[image]

which means `setForeground` will be inherited by `Swings` as its own class member, so you can call `setForeground` in `Swings` directly.

You can check [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4) for more details.

**update**

In java, if both non-static methods are in the same class, they can call each other directly, without creating a new instance.

Since `setForeground` is inherited by `Swings`, `setForeground` and `init` are both members of class `Swings`. So you can call `setForeground` in `init` directly.

Comment: But it is still a non-static method so won't it need an object to be called?

Comment: Is it true for the main method too? And I never read it in any java book or tutorial.

Comment: @shadyXV Notice, `main` method is `static`, so you can only call `static` methods without creating obejct in `main`. But in this case, `init` is not static, so you can call `setForeground` without creating obejct.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I am trying to improve my java skills , can you gice me any tips on how to practise and some good tutorial or books.

Comment: @shadyXV You can reference this online,  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.